# なんか after て- form of a verb

Tags: grammar

I am confused by the use of `なんか`, especially after the て-form of a verb. What do: `あきらめてなんかない`, `消えてなんかない` mean? How do they differ from simply saying `あきらめていない`, `消えていない`?　What is the purpose of `なんか`？

Comment: What is it about the て-verb usage in particular that is confusing? How about its use with nouns, like `お金なんかいらない`?

Comment: @PaulRichter I guess it's the construction that confuses me. お金なんかいらない would mean "I don't need things like money" compared to a simple お金いらない which is just "I don't need money" right?

Comment: 'I don't need money' would be お金'は'いらない, no? And お金なんかいらない can also be said as お金'など'いらない I think.

Comment: Related: [Usage of なんて and なんか as emphasis.](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/421/usage-of-%E3%81%AA%E3%82%93%E3%81%A6-and-%E3%81%AA%E3%82%93%E3%81%8B-as-emphasis)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Paul Richter's answer is partially right in the sense that `なんか` adds "emphasis against an assumption or statement by others and is used only in negative statements", but more accurately, `なんか` used here is not the same as `何か`, and it means `such thing as`.

> あきらめていない
> 'I have not given up.'
>
> あきらめて **なんか** (い)ない
> 'I haven't done **such thing as** giving up.'

Comment: I think the point of contention is not what it means but rather where it's derived from. Your answer would be great if you could shed light on its etymology. You still get a +1 for putting forth a clear concise answer though.

Comment: I would state explicitly that なんか・など disparages (the idea/mention of) the previous noun/verb. "Emphasis against" isn't specific/obvious enough, and "such things as" can be misinterpreted as representing nothing more than a list. But I think the idea of using "such a thing" is a good one for representing this nuance of なんか・など, so +1.

Comment: @sawa Btw is it true that [A]なんか always attaches a *derogatory feel* to [A] (like in the example sentence above)?

Comment: @Not necessarily. It can mean that [A] is far out of the scope of reality or reach or the context. `結婚なんかまだ考えられません`

Answer (score 2):

Not really different from [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/421/usage-of-%E3%81%AA%E3%82%93%E3%81%A6-and-%E3%81%AA%E3%82%93%E3%81%8B-as-emphasis).  Basically a weak `は`.

For your examples, they're essentially the same as `あきらめては(い)ない` and `消えては(い)ない` with the added nuance of `なんか` that the other post explains.

Comment: I do not think that introducing は helps understanding the construct.  あきらめてなんかない is closer to あきらめてない than あきらめてはいない or あきらめてはない.  (あきらめてはない sounds less natural to me than the other three, but this is a separate issue.)

Comment: @Flaw:  How does adding the `は` complicate things?

Answer (score 2):

For me なんか keeps his meaning whatever its position.
In this case, it's often to make your point. It can express surprise, anger etc...

> あきらめてなんかない => I did not give up "and it's not close".
>
> あきらめていない => I did not give up.

Answer (score 0):

なんか (何か）means "something" so in this case it can be taken as "or anything of the sort",  "...it's nothing like that", or "in any way". It gives emphasis against an assumption or statement by others and is used only in negative statements.

I would always include the い (...なんかいない rather than　...なんかない).

Comment: If I am not mistaken, なんか in the question is different from なんか which means “something” as in “なんか飲む?”  The latter is なにか with /i/ dropped, but なんか in the question cannot be replaced with なにか.

Comment: It's not syntactically the same (it couldn't be replaced), but morphologically it's clear so.

「あきらめてなんかはいない」 could be derived from:

「あきらめてるような何かはしていない」"I am not doing anything like giving up".

Comment: I doubt that they are morphologically the same.

Comment: isn't なんか a shorten version of なんていうか ?

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto: 「なんか」の「なん」は「何」なんかからきてないと言うことですか？ :)

Comment: Can my comment be interpreted in any other way?  I do not know, but the evidence you provided so far does not seem convincing to me.

Comment: http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&p=%E3%81%AA%E3%82%93%E3%81%8B&dtype=0&dname=0na&stype=0&index=13898500&pagenum=1　　

「あいつなんか（、）嫌い」「あいつ、なんか嫌い」 are completely different. Paul, could you elaborate on that "syntactically the same" and "morphologically the same" mean, exactly? Replaced and mean the same, or replaced and still be a valid sentence?

Comment: OPの言っている「なんか」は、「など」の口語的表現では？（「何か」とは関係ないと思います）

Comment: Is there any need to speak japanese here?

Comment: @oldergod san…　すみません・・PaulさんもTsuyoshiさんもdainichiさんも分かると思って手抜きしました・・ The なんか that the OP is talking about might be a colloquial version of など, like in 諦めてなどいない/消えてなどいない/お金などいらない etc. And I agree with Tsuyoshi-san, I don't think this なんか has anything to do with 何か, either.

Comment: dainichi's yahoo dictionary reference clearly states that なんか is a contraction of なに + か。Here are the four usage examples it gives, and my plausible translations:

`「この着物なんかお似合いです」A kimono such as this suits you.`

`「映画なんかよく行く」I go to places such as the movies.`

`「彼の言うことなんか聞くな」Don't listen to things such as what he says.`

`「君になんかわからない」Someone such as you wouldn't understand.`

The last two are exactly the same as the usage in the OP, as is the second definition.

Comment: If the link I provided above is reliable, the etymology of ～なんか is なにか, even if semantically it is more similar to ～など. I think this is supported by the fact that the dialectal なんぞ is used as both ～なんか and なん（に）か～

Comment: @dainichi san, Ahhh now I see, 国語なのに...知らないことがいっぱいです...orz

Comment: @chocolate pls speak as much jp as you want

Comment: @yadokari-san... Oh, I'm sorry... I know I shouldn't have...