# ような in the sentence and how to use?

Tags: grammar, translation

I'm having problem translating this sentence

> 正直な人が損をするようなことは、あってはいけない.

and more importantly I want to know what ”ような” means exactly in this context, please give me a short example of ”ような” if possible. I'm also curious what "あって" means too.

Sorry to bother and thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not "some grammar question" as the title suggests, but a request for translation, which is off-topic on Japanese.SE.

Comment: For your question about ような, we have at least 10 questions about it: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/search?q=%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%AA

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I dont understand ～ような in this context](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/4496/i-dont-understand-%ef%bd%9e%e3%82%88%e3%81%86%e3%81%aa-in-this-context)

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to translate the sentence just literally into English.

'There should not be things like an honest person suffer a loss.'

ような in this context means 'like' as a preposition.
Hence 'ようなこと' would be translated to 'things like~
あって is continuous form of the verb ある(to be or to exist)
As opposed to the e.g. below あって sounds very natural.

正直な人が損をするようなことは、'ある'はいけない。
 Here in this example'ある' , I intentionally remained in infinitive form. I can completely understand but conveys a feeling that the speaker is a novice Japanese learner.

Answer (score 0):

The structure is ような ＋ Noun
Yo na literally means like, similar to,such as, etc
So a person like this = ような人 
A thing like this = ようなもの

In the context,it means 'such as like making a loss'
The sentence means 'for an honest person, it is not possible he had things like loosing money.'