# What does 用なんてなくっても mean?

Tags: translation, meaning

Would it happen to be something roughly like "Even if I'm not busy"?

Comment: Not exact duplicate but may be of help: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/421/

Comment: Is there any more context available for where you found this phrase? ^^

Comment: I transliterated it from a doujinshi. And since that part was very tiny and handwritten, I'm not 100% sure about the first character, but I couldn't find anything else that looked like that. It's also a phrase that's in use, according to Google. 

The additional text by the same character is: 
たまにはいいじゃない
こんなにイイ天気なんだし
Every once in a while I like [to come here].
When the weather is nice like this. (Hope I got that right)

Comment: Is there really a っ in your sentence ?

Comment: Yes. I just double checked.

Answer (score 1):

用 here is close in meaning to 用事{ようじ}, indicating some task or purpose, sometimes translated "business". So in this case I believe it's "even if I don't have a particular reason/purpose/any business here...".  Possibly in response to some other comment along the lines of "何の用?"

If the additional text from comments is all part of the same then the first two parts go together and the third is offering an additional reason:

用なんてなくってもたまにはいいじゃない - Even if I don't have any business (here), it's fine (to do this/come here/etc) sometimes.

こんなにイイ天気なんだし - Since the weather's so nice, and all...

Comment: Thank you! It makes a lot more sense now when you put it together with the other lines and add "here" or "this place". And yes, it was a response to "何しに来た?".