# What does 乗ろうなんてした mean here?

Tags: meaning

> だいたい、どうして乗れもしないギアに乗ろうなんてしたのよ?

I think the translation is "Why did you get into the gear you can’t even ride, anyway?"

I guess なんて here emphasizes the previous part (乗れもしないギアに乗ろう), but I can't really understand using of 乗ろう. ～ろう forms volitional or presumptive verbs and it doesn't seem to work here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

なんて is phonic change from など と. In short, 乗ろうなんてした is the same as 乗ろう など と した or "tried to do such a thing as getting into".

Answer (score 0):

I think the other answers are fine.

I have had different image. He had made an attempt to do it, but failed it.

Why did you foray into riding the Gear you never had made it?