# Why does　なんてね　mean "Just kidding"?

Tags: grammar, set-phrases

I very often see なんてね or some similar phrase being translated to "Just kidding"? but why does it mean this and how does the grammar behind it work?

Answer (score 16):

なんて is an informal word that is used after some phrase and implies it is not important.

- [Usage of なんて and なんか as emphasis](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/421/5010)

  > Basically when you're kind of ignoring the importance of, or even slightly putting down, the topic of the sentence. 愛なんか要らない。(I don't need love!)
- [など; なんか; なんて](https://web.archive.org/web/20190311201757/http://www.jgram.org/pages/viewOne.php?tagE=nado%3B%20nanka%3B%20nante)

So when なんて is used like a standalone interjection, it means you said the previous sentence not seriously.

ね is a sentence-end particle and thus optional. You can say なんて! ("kidding!") without largely changing the meaning. なんてな is the same (sounds a bit more masculine).

Answer (score 10):

The verb 言う is omitted after なんて. So you can translate it "saying (something) like that", or virtually as a subjunctive: "(as if) it be/were like that". That's why it comes to have "I'm kidding" sense.

[image]
<sup>(Left: screen capture of [逆転裁判5](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%80%86%E8%BB%A2%E8%A3%81%E5%88%A4#.E9.80.86.E8.BB.A2.E8.A3.81.E5.88.A45), Right: the same cut on its English version, [Dual Destinies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoenix_Wright:_Ace_Attorney_%E2%88%92_Dual_Destinies).)</sup>

A synonymous expression is なんちゃって (< なんて言っちゃって). This one also works as a slangy adjective "pretend", as in なんちゃって家族 "a pretend family".

Answer (score 2):

"ｘｘｘなんてね"

> 『あんた（あんたは、あなたは）死んだ方がいいよ。』なんてね。
> I'd rather you were dead, just kidding.
> 『あんたは、死んだ方がいいよ。』なんて言ったりしてね。
> 『あんたは、死んだ方がいいよ』と、本気で言ったりしてね。
> 『あんたは、死んだ方がいいよ』(Once you said it cleary, then) って本気で言ったと思う？本気じゃないよ、冗談だよ。
> "I'd rather you were dead. (Once you said it cleary, then) Can I say it in earnest? NOWAY! I'm just saying it in fun."
> → I'd rather you were dead, just kidding.

もし、この説明で分かってもらえなかったら、もう僕はこのサイトに回答を投稿しないよ。なんてね。