# (意志形)〜ようとする + とか=ようとかする?

Tags: grammar

> 「それと、あくまでキスするのは今日の夜一二時だからね？士道に逃げられたりしたら困るから、無理に唇奪**おうとかしないでね**？」

Is the bold part a combination of (意志形)〜ようとする and とか (so that the とか is used in place of と)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is とか in this sentence. The basic meaning of ～とか is "things like ～". But its main role here is to soften the sentence by signaling the speaker is aware that it's unlikely. 唇奪おうとしないでね without とか can sound like a serious request, but with とか, the sentence sounds more like a half-joke.

明鏡国語辞典 has this explanation:

> #### とか
>
> 〔若者ことばで〕断定の調子を避けてやわらげる。
> 「まだ用意━できてない」「さすが山田さん━言っちゃって」「いやだな━思わない？」
> ▶ 伝統的な言い方では、ほぼ「など」「でも」に当たる。

とか has replaced と in the last two examples. "嫌だなとか思わない?" sounds milder than "嫌だなと思わない?", as if "I guess?" or "maybe?" were added.

[なんて](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/43769/5010) has a similar function: 唇奪おうなんて思わないでね? / 唇奪おうなんてしないでね? (the latter is less common)