# How is なんて used here at the beginning of a sentence?

Tags: reading-comprehension

[image]

So one of the character wonders about the relationship between the two people and asks character B this: "Would you come this far when you are only shopkeeper and client"?

[image]
[image]

The answer seems to be "Those kind of things also happen. After all, right now he has a lot of friends (phrasing). However how is なんて here being used?

Comment: The provided contexts are not enough, but most probably, it's an instance of [Why does なんてね mean "Just kidding"?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/43769) (without ね).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does　なんてね　mean "Just kidding"?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/43769/why-does-%e3%81%aa%e3%82%93%e3%81%a6%e3%81%ad-mean-just-kidding)

Comment: Bluegate, since the context you provide is insufficient, even native speakers are confused too often. Please always try to explain the situation more concretely. Who are they? What kind of place is this こんなところ?

Answer (score 0):

The usage doesn't sound correct to me. なんせ makes more sense but that's still odd (because it ends with かな but なんせ implies the speaker knows it to be true, so it sounds odd).

Maybe it was a mistake by the author? Maybe something got replaced and なんせ was forgotten to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

The basic meaning of なんて is explained here: [Why does　なんてね　mean "Just kidding"?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/43769/5010)

Specifically in this context, this なんて indicates "客と店員がこんなところまで来ますか" was a question said half-jokingly to baffle the listener. That is, he asked it even though he did know that a shopkeeper and a client might well visit that place. I think "Just kidding" is an okay translation.

Comment: How did you read 友人の割合? After another look I suppose he may  be saying "The friendship ratio between me and him is higher (than client-shopkeeper)

Comment: @Bluegate I don't know. It should be easy if there is enough context, but please don't make us play a guessing game based on limited clues. It's best to paste several pages, but if you don't like that, give us the title of the manga and the chapter number so people can check it out.