# How does なんていう + のも function in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, translation

The premise is a young girl's entire family claim to be in service to 龍神 as fortune tellers. They own the Hoju Jewel which allows them to have clairvoyant powers and they use their station to connect the dragon world to the human world. Their eccentric way of going about explaining this to her embarrasses her so this is just a sentence relaying to the reader what she's been taught. She doesn't seem to believe in any of it.

> その龍が神様だ、なんていうのもウソくさいし、うちみたいな田舎の占い屋が、人間界の代表であることもウソくさい。

My translation:

> "That dragon is a god - this is what I'd call a sham, as is some rural fortuneteller being the god's representative for the human realm."

I'm not too sure about the なんていう + のも. I want to keep the main idea intact. I'm learning how to translate and localize text. A breakdown of this sentence would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A more literal translation of the first half of the sentence is:

> 〖「その龍が神様だ」なんて言うの〗もウソくさい
>   〖Saying "That dragon is a god"〗 is contrived, (as well as...)

- なんて is used in place of quoatative-と. なんて is used to make light of the marked part.  See: [Usage of なんて and なんか as emphasis](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/421/5010) Simply put, なんて言う is a nuanced version of と言う.
- 言う is just "to say".
- の is a nominalizer.
- も is "also". (used in relation to the second half of the entire sentence)
- 嘘くさい is almost a single-word adjective, "contrived", "false-sounding".

Your translation seems basically okay, but "what I'd call a sham" might be too strong. The sentence is saying "hard to believe", not "impossible to believe".