# What does "なんてもんに" mean in this sentece?

Tags: parsing

> 普段から俺は、病気なんてもんに縁がなかった。

I know some of the meanings of なんて and here I think it's just a word to emphasize 病気 in the sentence, but I don't understand that **もんに**. I think it has something to do with もの, maybe the regular 物. Also, I'm not sure but it seems that the reading of 縁 is "えん", which apparently means either *fate* or *relationship/link*, because there's also a "ふち" reading which means *edge* but it wouldn't make sense here. My guess:

> I usually didn't have any connection with the illness.

Also, if I was right with my guess, can I say that "もんに縁がなかった" has a literal meaning of "There wasn't a connection with that **thing** (もの→病気)"? In this case, is もんに repeating the noun 病気, similar to **そんなものに**?

Comment: Duplicate? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/1823/45489

Comment: @sundowner I don't know. Is なんて a contraction of ～というもの, ～などという  or などというもの? There's a contraction between the second and third answer. Even though those answers are quite useful, that question itself is about なんて and なんか, and it doesn't answer clearly about the relationship of なんて and もの. Also, I still need help to parse the sentence because of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is the relevant definition of [なんて](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%AA%E3%82%93%E3%81%A6/#jn-165854), which derives from などと.

> ３ ある事物を例示して、次の語と同格であることを示す。…などという。「田中―人、知らない」「人間―ものはちっぽけなもんです」

もん is a slangy form of もの, so technically なんて indicates that 病気 is in apposition to もの. なんてもん is a less polite version of などというもの, and 病気なんて**いう**もの is also possible.

Practically Xなんてもん means "such a thing/things as/called X (in general)". The sentence means "I've never had any connection with such a thing as illness", meaning the speaker has never had health problems whatsoever.

The particular usage of なんてもん can be replaced by なんか for degrading the preceding noun.

- 会社なんてもんは信用できない One can never trust any company.
- iPhoneなんてもんはぜいたく品だ (Such a thing as) iPhone is a luxury.

Answer (score 1):

"nantemon" if form  "nado to iu mono".
"mon" is "mono" changed by euphony that means a pronunciation of letters and syllables which is pleasing to the ear.

in this case "mono" is a category of disease or illness.

Comment: So, can the sentence be written as "**普段から俺は、病気などというものに縁がなかった。**"? If that's the case, is my attempt of translating to English correct?